# How to transfer a particular file into a directory?

Tags: c

In this code, I am trying to copy a file and paste it into a directory. As you can see that I printed the path of that file also that is `subPaths1[1]` and it get printed successfully but when I `transfer()` it, the result is the following and it didn't copy. How can I transfer/copy that particular file into a directory?

**Given Output**

```
/home/runner/TestC1/fileName.txt
rsync: change_dir "/home/runner/TestC1/fileName.txt" failed: Not a directory (20)
rsync error: some files/attrs were not transferred (see previous errors) (code 23) at main.c(1196) [sender=3.1.2]
```

**Part 1**

```
int listdir(char *basePath, char files[][SIZE], int *total){
    char path[PATH_MAX];
    struct dirent *dp;
    DIR *dir;

    if (NULL != (dir = opendir(basePath))) {//try to open dir
        while(NULL != (dp = readdir(dir))) {//iterate through contents
            if (strcmp ( dp->d_name, ".") != 0 && strcmp ( dp->d_name, "..") != 0) {
                snprintf(path, SIZE, "%s/%s", basePath, dp->d_name);
                if (dp->d_type == DT_REG) {
                    if (*total < ELEMENTS) {
                        snprintf (files[*total], SIZE, "%s", path);
                        files[*total][SIZE - 1] = 0;
                        ++(*total);
                    }
                }
                if(dp->d_type == DT_DIR){
                    listdir(path, files, total);
                }
            }
        }
        closedir(dir);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**Part 2**

```
char *transfer(char *f1, char *f2){
    char cmd[500];
    snprintf(cmd, 500, "rsync -a %s/ %s", f1, f2);
    system(cmd);

    return 0;
}

int main(){
    char basePath1[SIZE] = "/home/runner/TestC1", pathWords1[ELEMENTS][SIZE], path[ELEMENTS];
    int countPaths1 = 0;

    listdir(basePath1, pathWords1, &countPaths1);
    char subPaths1[5][SIZE];
    for(int i=0; i<5; i++){
        strcpy(subPaths1[i], pathWords1[i]);
    }
    printf("%s\n", subPaths1[1]);
    transfer(subPaths1[1], "/home/runner/TestC1/folder1");

    return 0;
  }
```

Comment: It tells you exactly, no? It expects a directory name, but you give it a file. Print your `cmd` and try running the same in the console

Answer (score 0):

you can use the `rename` syscall
for example:

```
#include <stdio.h> // for rename function
int main() {
    char *old_path = "/home/runner/TestC1/fileName.txt";
    char *new_path = "/home/runner/fileName.txt";
    rename(old_path, new_path);
}
```

please see [rename() man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/rename.2.html)

`rename` move the file from dir to another but if you want to copy the file you should read from the old file and copy to the new file byte by byte